# Limit with series continued to infinite natural numbers

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac1{n^2+n+1}+\frac2{n^2+n+2}+\frac3{n^2+n+3}+\dots$$
($n\in\Bbb N$.) I am unable to form formula for sum of this series, but when I tried find the value where it converges I got 0.5. Why?

Comment: What is the last term?And how did you get that it converges to $0.5$?

Comment: Use calculator and use about 7 to 8 terms it will approach 0.5. ... Further increase in no of would take you even closer to 0.5

Answer (score 1):

If what your looking for is 
$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}(\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{k}{n²+n+k})$, you have an issue since none of the series $\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{k}{n²+n+k}$ converges : the general term $\frac{k}{n²+n+k}$ tends to 1 when $k\rightarrow\infty$.

Comment: n  is varying from 1 to infinity not k

Comment: Sorry you are right but k goes from 1 to n not infinity

Comment: Ok, then the question makes sense, but you should edit it so everybody knows the last term is $\frac{n}{n^2+n+n}$...

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you know about harmonic numbers $$S_n=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{k}{n²+n+k}=n(n+1)  \left(H_{n(n+1)}-H_{n (n+2)}\right)+n$$ Now, consider the asymptotics $$H_p=\gamma+\log(p)+\frac{1}{2
   p}+O\left(\frac{1}{p^2}\right)$$ which makes $$H_{n(n+1)}-H_{n (n+2)}=\frac{1}{2 n (n+1)}-\frac{1}{2 n (n+2)}+\log \left({n
   (n+1)}\right)-\log \left({n (n+2)}\right)+\cdots$$ that is to say $$H_{n(n+1)}-H_{n (n+2)}=\frac{1}{2 n^3+6 n^2+4 n}+\log\left(1-\frac{1}{n+2}\right)+\cdots$$ Now, using long division for the first term and Taylor series for the second $$H_{n(n+1)}-H_{n (n+2)}=-\frac{1}{n}+\frac{3}{2 n^2}-\frac{11}{6
   n^3}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^4}\right)$$ and then $$S_n=\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{3
   n}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)$$ which shows the limit and also how it is approached.